# view is not updated in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, view, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an issue when I try to display data.

- I send my form and update my database *(it works great, backend is ok)*
- I use a button on the page to return to homepage
- The view of the homepage is not updated, always the same values. 
  (It seems that there is only the template that loads, not with queries)

**I need to click on the button refresh of the browser to see new values.**

After the 'hard' refresh, the view is updated.

Why do I need to completely refresh the page ?

Here is my code

**JS :**

My service `GenericService`
(I created this service because I use this in several controllers)

```
myApp.factory('GenericService', function ($http, $q, MyFunctions) {
    var data = {};

    function getDataIfNeeded(action) {

        action = action || 'default';

        if (data[action] !== undefined) {
            return $q.when(data[action]);
        }

        return $http({
            url: "php/functions.php",
            method: "GET",
            params: { 
                action: action, 
                dummy: MyFunctions.randomString(7)
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            data[action] = response.data;
            return data[action];
        });
    }

    return {
        getData: getDataIfNeeded
    };
});
```

The call of the service

```
myApp.controller('listCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', '$location', 'GenericService',
function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location, GenericService) {

  GenericService.getData("get_projects").then(function (data) {
    $scope.projects = data;
  }); 

  GenericService.getData("get_projects_draft").then(function (data) {
    $scope.projects_in_draft = data;
  }); 

 }]);
```

**HTML :**

```
<div ng-controller="listCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="project in projects">
       <span>{{ project.nom }}</span>
 </div>
 <div ng-repeat="project_draft in projects_in_draft">
       <span>{{ project_draft.nom }}</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Update the private variable `data` in `GenericService` when you send your form, in order to keep the data in sync?

Comment: If you've already been to your homepage, the `if (data[action] !== undefined)` sends a `return` and prevent your code from requesting new data

Comment: Your `getDataIfNeeded` will only _get data if **needed**_.  You need to update the cached value of `data`.

Comment: Yeah, you're all right ! Thanks ! Problem solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your service `GenericService` fetch the data from the server only "if needed", which means if the local `data` variable isn't empty. Naturally, without reloading the service and after a form submission, the data will be out-of-sync! So you have two choices:

**If the server is creating additional data**, i.e. possesses data that AngularJS don't have after the form submission, you need to do another request in order to fetch the new data. Just **empty** the local `data` variable.

**Else**, if the server is just saving the data in a database for instance, and doesn't perform any other operation with an impact on what is shown on your page, you don't have to do an other request, since you already know what you sent to the server! Just **update** the local `data` variable.