# angularjs - objects update and view refresh

Tags: php, json, angularjs

I create a page that can `add`, `edit`, `delete` users. I use `php` to save the updated `object` into `json` file.

```
  $scope.save = function() {
    $http.post('php/saveusers.php', $scope.users).then(function() {
        // log success
        console.log($scope.users);
        console.log("php called");
        });
  }
```

My problem is the `view` update is not consistent. Every time I `add`, `edit`, `delete`, the `json` will be updated. But it `html` sometimes update to new one, sometimes it doesn't. Even I refresh the page many times. The `console.log($scope.users);` shows the latest result every time. But when I refresh the page, it goes back to the old one.

I believe it is the similar problem with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658467/view-is-not-updated-in-angularjs). But I don't know how to **empty** or **update** local `data` variable.

**Update:**
This is my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QXbYYQIz0xMNhj1V5Yns?p=preview).

Comment: I bet your $scope.users data is a string.

Comment: It is an object. something like `[{"name":"john","position":"designer"},{"name":"mary","position":"ceo"}]`.

Comment: Whats the HTML? Does the model have a dot, aka {{users.name}}, or is it {{users}} ? Its impossible to answer your question when you leave out the data, most of the JS & the HTML.

Comment: I added plunker in my update. Please take a look. I added together with `php` I used to update `json`. Not sure if it works on plunker though.

Comment: How do you do server updates if there are no unique identifiers for each user? Why do all users get sent when you only need to update one? Should probably show us the php. Also, learn to inspect actual ajax request in browser dev tools network so you can see exactly what gets sent and what gets returned

Comment: Is there er certain chain of events that lead to misbehavior? The plnkr seems to work...

Comment: Yes it does work locally. The problem lies after `php` update the `json`, I am not so sure of what `$scope.users` hold after then. I did tried `console.log($scope.users)` at several places it seems ok. But the moment I refresh the page it goes back to the old one, even though `json` already have different data. I strongly believe it is at the `$scope` level.